# Doubts with Java Primitive Data type (Byte and Int)

Tags: java

When i do the below code, it ask me for casting the value on right side ?

```
byte myByteTestValue = Byte.MAX_VALUE + 1;
```

When i do the below code, it didn't ask me for casting the value on right side ?

```
int myIntTestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1;
```

why this is happening, anyone can explain ?

Comment: `Byte.MAX_VALUE + 1` means `Byte.MAX_VALUE + int`

Answer (score 3):

The `+ 1` is treated as an Integer which is larger than a byte.  Cast it and the warning goes away.

```
byte myByteTestValue = Byte.MAX_VALUE + (byte)1;
```